# String starts with a defined set of words

Tags: php, arrays, string

How to know if a given string starts with a defied set of words?

```
$allowed = array("foo", "bar");
```

pseudocode:

```
$boolean = somefunction($allowed,'food');
```

$boolean should be TRUE

Comment: The [strpos()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) function might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function somefunction($allowed, $word) {
    $result = array_filter(
        $allowed,
        function ($value) use ($word) {
            return strpos($word, $value) === 0;
        }
    );
    return (boolean) count($result);
}

$boolean = somefunction($allowed,'food');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function doesStringStartWith($string, $startWithOptions)
{
    foreach($startWithOptions as $option)
    {
        if(substr($string, 0, strlen($option)) == $option) // comment this for case-insenstive
        // uncomment this for case-insenstive: if(strtolower(substr($string, 0, strlen($option))) == strtolower($option))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

$result = doesStringStartWith('food', array('foo', 'bar'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that all of your prefixes are the same length you could do this:

```
if ( in_array( substr($input,0,3), $allowed ) {
    // your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following function:

```
function testPos($allowed,$s) {
    $a = 0;
    while($a < count($allowed)) {
        if(strpos($s,$allowed[$a]) === 0) {
            return true;
        }
        $a++;
    }
}
```

Now you can try:

```
$allowed = array('foo','bar');
echo testPos($allowed,'food');
```